# How to read local country phone codes xml in titanium alloy

Tags: javascript, xml, titanium, titanium-alloy

In my application I get the country code using Titanium.Locale.getCurrentCountry(); , I then want to match this country code with this xml : https://code.google.com/p/country-phone-codes/ to find the corresponding country name and phone code. I am using titanium alloy so where should I put this xml in my project and how can I parse this xml to get the country name and phone code required ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just convert this to [JSON (here is a fiddle, I did it for you)](http://jsfiddle.net/tbXbu/1/) and put it inside a file called `countries.js`, put this file inside your `app/lib/` folder (create it if it does not exist) and then call it from code like this:

```
var countries = require('countries');
// Lookup the country name and phone code by country code
var name = countries['us'].name;
var phoneCode = countries['us'].phoneCode;
```